# Plotting a 3D vector field on 2D plane

Tags: plotting, vector

I want to visualize vector field that is of the form 
$(v_1(x,y), v_2(x,y), v_3(x,y))$,
i.e. there is a three component vector that depends on only two coordinates $x$ and $y$ in the real plane. There are *Mathematica* functions `VectorPlot[]` and `VectorPlot3D[]` but both of them assume that the dimensionality of the space is the same as the number of vector components. In the latest version of *Mathematica* there also seems to be something called `SliceVectorPlot3D[]`, but I don't have this in my *Mathematica* so I would prefer to use some other way. Furthermore, if it matters at all, the vectors are normalized so that I only care about the direction of the vector at a given point on the plane.

How do I do this?

EDIT: Here's an example of something I would like to get:

[image: example]

Comment: ...shouldn't you be using `ParametricPlot3D[]` for this instead?

Comment: Ah, so you want the **normal vectors** of a surface, then?

Comment: Not normals. The surface is just a regular 2D plane (i.e. normals would be all point up), but for every point of the plane is attached one 3D vector that I would like to visualize.

Comment: This may be a little late. I would like to mention that new versions of Mathematica has a function "SliceVectorPlot3D" just for this. The second example in the help documentation is very similar to the task at hand here. But I cauting, this function seems to be a little buggy. I am struggling to use it with complex surfaces. I. Konuk

Comment: @I.Konuk Never too late, my friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do this with graphics primitives:

```
v = Flatten[
   Table[ { x , y  , { Sin[x ] , Cos[ y] , 2} } , {x, -Pi, 
     Pi, .5} , {y, -Pi, Pi, .5}], 1];
Graphics3D[{Red, 
    Arrow[Tube[{{#[[1]], #[[2]], 
        0}, {#[[1]] + #[[3, 1]], #[[2]] + #[[3, 2]], #[[3, 
          3]]}}]]} & /@ v, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Another take, using `ListPointPlot3D`:

Define vector field on the x-y plane:

```
f[x_, y_] = {.3 Sin[x], .3 Cos[y], 1}
```

Define grid on the x-y plane where the vector tails will be placed:

```
data = Flatten[Table[{x, y, 0}, {x, -Pi, Pi, Pi/4}, {y, -Pi, Pi, Pi/4}], 1]
```

Plot with `ListPointPlot3D` using a replacement rule to convert points to vectors:

```
ListPointPlot3D[data] /. Point[a_] :> (Arrow[Tube[{#, # + f @@ Most@#}, .05]] & /@ a)
```

Easily extendable to arbitrary surfaces (just add some `z[x,y]` instead of `0` in the `data` specification.

```
z[x_, y_] = .3 Sin[x] + .3 Cos[y];
data = Flatten[Table[{x, y, z[x, y]}, {x, -Pi, Pi, Pi/4}, {y, -Pi, Pi, Pi/4}], 1];
ListPointPlot3D[data] /. {Point[a_] :> (Arrow[Tube[{#, # + f @@ Most@#}]] & /@ a)};
ListPlot3D[data];
Show[{%, %%}, PlotRangePadding -> {.3, .3, {.1, .9}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[@J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) is right. Define each vector as a function (eg `v1[x_,y_]:=x+y`) and then use `ParametricPlot3D[]` parametrized for `x` and `y`.

Example:

```
v1[x_, y_] := Sin[x]*y;
v2[x_, y_] := Cos[x]*y;
v3[x_, y_] := x;
ParametricPlot3D[{v1[x, y], v2[x, y], v3[x, y]},
 {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, {y, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}]
```

Comment: This draws a surface parametrized by my vector. I want the result to look like VectorPlot3D but only on a surface. The vectors can of course stick out from the surface, but their starting points need to be on it.

Comment: Something like that? https://www.dropbox.com/s/spyrb0peho5vh39/V1.pdf?dl=0

Comment: More like this: http://postimg.org/image/la0kismuh/ (from some random article I managed to find)